# C++ GL glRectf()// How to work function

Tags: c++

I want to draw rectangles and circles and find is there any intertection.But I dont understand how to work glRectf() function?Where is the rectangle's center.Top left corner,bottom left corner or exactly center of shape?____2.Que::If the center is left top or bottom,how can I find these two object intersect?

[image: shapes]

Comment: OpenGL does not deal with detecting intersections at all.

Comment: If I can finf how to work glRectf() function,I can write code

Comment: Where is the rectangle center

Comment: How is [the documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRect.xml) not clear enough? You pass in two opposite corners, so the center is between those two.

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRect.xml

If i understood well the documentations says that

```
void glRectd(GLdouble x1,  GLdouble y1,  GLdouble x2,  GLdouble y2);
```

x1 and y1 are the coordinates of one vertex and
x2 and y2 are the coordinates of the opposite one.
This is becouse i think that opencl cl work with triangles.
Geometry is simple it teach to us that a can be diveded into two equals part wich are two rectangle triangles. So this two points are the vertices of these triangles where the angle aren't the rigth angle.
In addition the rectangle hypotenuse of this triangle

Here a specification about the coordinates system

http://www.falloutsoftware.com/tutorials/gl/gl0.htm

Comment: Triangles have nothing to do with how this API is specified. It's just two opposite corners, which is a perfectly fine way to define a rectangle in this context.